# How to Append a string after some specific characker in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a script to download video from youtube but i want to add *ss* just after the *www.* to it will be converted into *www.ssyoutube.com*

```
 #!/bin/bash
 dialog --inputbox "Enter Video's Link..." 10 30 2>/tmp/video.txt
 video=`cat /tmp/video.txt`       
 edit=ss 
 echo $video
 sleep 5;
 wget $video
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sed. Use a escaped dot in your regex to match a literal dot.

```
sed 's/www\./www.ss/g' file
```

ie,

```
sed -i 's/www\./www.ss/g' /tmp/video.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

[Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) can do this for you in bash.

```
video="www.youtube.com"
edit="ss"
video="${video/www./www.$edit}"
echo "$video"                   # www.ssyoutube.com
```

`man bash` → search for "Pattern substitution."

(Sure, `sed` works too, but for a simple string substitution it's much more efficient to use `bash`'s built-in feature than to fork a new process.)